# twitter bootstrap - minimum width column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this has to have been asked before, but i don't think my "terms" are correct.

i have a page that has text, and then an image. When the image ends, i would like the text to flow under the image.

So,

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-10  col-xs-offset-1  ">
      <div class="hero-unit row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 ">
            <h2 class="welcome">welcome</h2>
          </div>

         <div class="col-xs-8 ">
            <p>some text here</p>

            <p>imagine there is more text here</p>

            <p>just, the most text ever.</p>
         </div>//col-xs-8

         <div class="solidClass col-xs-4 ">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/WebContent/img/both.png" alt="screenshots"/>
         </div>        

      </div>//hero-unit-row
   </div> //col-xs-10
</div>//row
```

in the scenario above, the text in the "col-xs-8" row should overflow when the text gets past the image in the col-xs-4 row.

is there something i can tell bootstrap by way of a class, or something i can add to a specialty class to make this happen?

Comment: Both the text, and the image would have to be inside the same element, with the image floating to one side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you would need for this layout is the next:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="solidClass col-xs-4 pull-right">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="screenshots" />
    </div>

    <p>some text here</p>
    <p>imagine there is more text here</p>
    <p>just, the most text ever.</p>
</div>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/vSq4rsJPbjfvdn6FYiR9?p=preview

Two important points:

1. Extend "left" text container to full width with `.col-xs-12` class.
2. Move image container into text container and float it right with `pull-right` class.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your intended effect, the image has to be in the same parent element as the text.

You can then use bootstrap's `pull-right` class to float the element to the right.

I, also, assume that you intended for the text to be able to fit the full 12 col width. If you want the image to still be limited to a 4 column width, you can wrap it in a bootstrap `col-xs-4` class.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-10  col-xs-offset-1  ">
      <div class="hero-unit row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 ">
            <h2 class="welcome">welcome</h2>
          </div>

         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="/WebContent/img/both.png" alt="screenshots"/>
            </div>
            <p>some text here</p>

            <p>imagine there is more text here</p>

            <p>just, the most text ever.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Bootply here: http://www.bootply.com/hANj4uFgb2